# Tabletop.js with Google Sites

Tags: javascript, google-sites

I am trying to integrate Tabletop.js with Google Sites. Here's my Tabletop-related code:

```
$(function() {
    var public_spreadsheet_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SAMPLE_URL/pubhtml';

    Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url,
             callback: displayEntries } );
});

function displayEntries(data, tabletop) {
    var page = SitesApp.getActivePage();
    var student = page.getName();

    var entries = tabletop.sheets(student).all();
    Logger.log(entries);

    for (i=entries.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var eventname = entries[i].event;
        var judge = entries[i].judge;
        var comments = entries[i].comments;

    $('.comment-list').append('<li class="comment-entry"><span class="event">' + eventname + '</span><span class="judge">Judge: ' + judge + '</span><p class="comment-body">'+ comments + '</p></li>');
    }
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div class="comments">
<ul class="comment-list">
  <!-- here is where tabletop data is inserted -->
</ul>
</div>
```

I've fiddled with a couple of options, including inserting an HTML Box and creating a web app with Google Apps Script to embed as a gadget in the page, but HTML Boxes seem to have trouble importing the Tabletop.js script file, and I can't figure out the GAS webapp route. What's the easiest way to get this to work?